# I need to prove that $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I need to prove that $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$, by the this theorem:
$G/\ker(\varphi)\cong Im(\varphi)$.

I tried to find $\varphi$ that will give me this but I didn't succeed.

Maybe it's a mistake at my H.W.
But if not, I'll be glad if you will help me...

Thank you!

Comment: $(\mathbb C,+)$ you mean?

Comment: @B.S. I this yes - $\mathbb{C}$ with + action... ($0\in \mathbb{C}$)

Comment: Find a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ with kernel $\mathbb R$. These are $\mathbb R$-vector spaces that we are dealing with, there are canonical bases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Assuming you mean $\langle\mathbb{C},+\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbb{R},+\rangle$: consider $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $\varphi(z)=\operatorname{im}(z)$, i.e. $\varphi(x+iy)=y$.

Comment: Wow, great!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think the map $(a+ib)\mapsto a$ would be helpful.

Comment: $\ker=\mathbb{R}$??

Comment: Yes. $\text{ker}(f)=\{a+ib\mid a=0\}\cong\mathbb R$ where $f$ is my map.

Comment: the kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$